# Usage of extern variable in C

Tags: c

When I was going through an `extern` variable concept,  I came across this snippet:

```
int array[10]; // in file1.c
extern int *array; // in file2.c
```

The explanation was as follows, semantics of array is different in two files. The linker can't resolve the name and at the same time won't flag an error, but the programs fails at run time.

But when I tried this out, neither it failed at run time even nor did I get any warnings.

My doubt is can I use any semantics, while and using `extern` mean if my extern variable is of type `int`, can the other variable be of type pointer or array !!!

Will it be correct, can any one please explain me this?

Comment: No, it won't be correct, you can't do this. It was mere luck (or rather, bad luck) that your program didn't fail at runtime.

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/q/14697698/1809377

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You couldn't. Please refer to Jens Gustedt's answer and use the acceptable syntax.

Let's consider what will happen if you define an array and declare it as a pointer in another file.

```
int array[10];      // in file1.c
extern int *array;  // in file2.c
```

We all know that global variables, interpreted as different symbols, have definite addresses in compilation. We got the variable values by loading from their addresses. So in this case below:

```
int array[10];
```

If we would like to know the value of `array[0]`, first of all we find out the address of symbol `array`, let's say `0x20132014`. Then we add the index `0` to this address, and get the value of `array[0]` from this address `0x20132014`;

While in another case:

```
int *p;
```

Similarly, all we have is the address of symbol `p`. This is an address of a pointer. So if we like to know the value of `p[0]`, an extra step should be done. First we get the address of symbol `p`, say `0x12345678`, and find out the value of `p`, which is stored in `0x12345678`. This value, say `0x10101010`, is the address of the variable which `p` is pointing to (namely `p[0]`). We're actually loading from address `0x10101010` to get the value of `p[0]`.

Let's look back to check out what will happen if we define an array and declare it as a pointer in another file:

In file2, we would like to use `array[0]` to get the value of the first element in the array. But since in this file, `array` is declared as a pointer, the address of symbol `array` is regarded as an address of pointer, so the value stored in this address is regarded as the address of `array[0]`, as stated above. However, this value is actually the value of `array[0]` and not an address. In this case, we're trying to loading from an inappropriate address, and would possibly cause a run-time error.

The root is because the compiler defines different methodologies when dealing with different types. So keep the types matched in all the declarations.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that, that behavior is undefined. If you don't know the size of the array in the second file, you can use the following syntax:

```
int array[10]; // in file1.c
extern int array[]; // in file2.c
```

This helps you to access the array in `file2.c`. The only thing that you can't do there is `sizeof array`.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not correct. It's ill-formed and would lead to undefined behavior or segmentation fault depending upon what you do with `array` in `file2.c`.

In `file1.c` you **define** `array` to be of type `array` of 10 `int`s. In `file2.c` you **declare** `array` to be of type `int *`. During linking phase, the linker, well, links the identifier `array` in `file2.c` with its definition in `file1.c`. So basically, the same memory location is accessed in two different files as different types which can clearly lead to problems.

If you try to dereference  `array` in `file2.c`, then depending on the size of pointer on your system, the first element or the first two elements together will be interpreted as a memory address and will most likely lead to segmentation fault.

```
// in file2.c
// may cause seg fault

int x = *array;
```

The correct way to do it is

```
// in file2.c
// sizeof may not be applied to array in this scope
// because array is incomplete type until linked.

extern int array[];
```

You must match the type of the variable in its declaration with its external definition. The linker doesn't check for types of variables when resolving references of symbols. Only functions have the types of the function encoded into the function name. Therefore you won't get any warning or error and it would compile just fine.

Technically, the linker or some compiler component could track what type the symbol represents, and then give an error or warning. But there is no requirement from the standard to do so. You are required to do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

You need know that the type of `array` is `int [10]`, it cann't be casted to `int *`.

```
int array[10];        // in file1.c
extern int array[10]; // in file2.c
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use it this way.extern with another type.
But it only confuse you of the exact type of the array.
If you extern a function without telling the return type compiler will always set the return type to int.In some case you may get you return value cutted.

in file1.c array is an array of int 10.

in file2.c array is pointer which point to none and have same address with array in file1.

I use gdb to test.

array in file2.c is

```
(gdb) p array
$2 = (int *) 0x0
(gdb) p &array
$3 = (int **) 0x804a040
```

I've set numbers for array.

```
(gdb) x/10 &array
0x804a040 <array>:  0   1   2   3
0x804a050 <array+16>:   4   5   6   7
0x804a060 <array+32>:   8   9
```

to access to array in file2.c you need cast array to int* type

```
(gdb) p/d ((int*)&array)[9]
$8 = 9
```

in file1.c array is a normal array.

```
(gdb) p array[2]
$11 = 2
```

please note you can't use array in file2.c as you do in file1.c.You will get a segmentation fault.